# jquery scrollto not scrolling to correct element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop, scrollto

I have a div element with `overflow-y` set to `auto`. Now I have bunch of elements with class as `highlight1`. I want to scroll back and forth on the elements with the `class` as `highlight1`.

For some reason jquery `scrollTo` is not working properly. This is the syntax I am trying to use:

```
$('#highlightDiv').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#"+elementId).offset().top + 'px'
}, 'fast');
```

Here is the [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yknqsg7w/) of what I am trying to accomplish. Can some one explain why the scroll is not moving to proper element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've simple answer Your script doesn't know height and position of scroll of the div that You are scrolling you should add two values to it and it should work

scrollTop in function **scrollToNextHighlight()** should look like this

```
scrollTop: ($('#highlightDiv').scrollTop() - 
$('#highlightDiv').offset().top)
+ $("#"+elementId).offset().top + 'px'
```

and then it should work

Comment: can you please explain why you are adding this: $('#highlightDiv').scrollTop() - 
$('#highlightDiv').offset().top

Comment: this ($('#highlightDiv').scrollTop() - $('#highlightDiv').offset().top) counts position of scroll from the top of div #highlightDiv cause you add only position of element scroll will be counted from top of body